# How can change every bit in byte variable

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have one byte number

```
// in decimal
byte number = 250
// result who I want is number = 5

// in binary 
byte number = 0b11111010
// result who I want is number = 0b00000101
```

How can I reverse every bit in this number? I try with shift left, shift right operations, with OR, AND but is not doing this what I need.

Comment: I haven't really worked with this kind of data in c#, but I noticed you didn't mention a bitwise NOT operator. Would that not do what you want?

Comment: @OliverNicholls how can I write this NOT operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the bitwise `not` operator `~`

```
byte b = 0b11111111;
byte flipped = ~b; // 0b00000000
```

EDIT: Explanation taken from MSDN

> The ~ operator looks at the binary representation of the values of the expression and does a bitwise negation operation on it.
>   Any digit that is a 1 in the expression becomes a 0 in the result. Any digit that is a 0 in the expression becomes a 1 in the result.
>   When the ~ operator acts on an operand of an integral data type, it performs no coercion and returns a value of the same data type as the operand. When the operand is of a non-integral data type, the value is coerced to type int before the operation is performed, and the return value of the operator is of type int.

Comment: Is working. Thanks for the help